# PHP form input syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, input, syntax-error

While making a form to input data into a table, I keep getting the following error;

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES  ('Michael Everhart','Toyoda,''Machine Shop ESP','2013-08-02','','','' at line 2on the server."

As a PHP beginner I can't seem to locate the syntax error that I have. Can anyone help me with this please?

Here's the code:

```
mysql_select_db("audits", $con);

$fixed ="0";
$safety="INSERT INTO audits.safety
 (Auditor,Area,ESP, Date, SOT1, SOT2, SOT3, SOT4, SOT5, SOT6, SOT7, SOT8, SOT9, SOT10, SOT11, SOT12, SOT13, SOT14, SOT15, SOT16, SOT17, SOT18, SOT19, fixed)
VALUES
 ('$name','$area,''$esp','$when','$SOT1','$SOT2','$SOT3','$SOT4','$SOT5','$SOT6','$SOT7','$SOT8','$SOT9','$SOT10','$SOT11','$SOT12','$SOT13','$SOT14','$SOT15','$SOT16','$SOT17','$SOT18','$SOT19', $fixed)";
mysql_query ($safety,$con);
IF (!mysql_query($safety,$con))
{
die('Error: '. errorMail());
  }
  echo "1 safety finding added";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
VALUES
 ('$name','$area,''$esp',
                ^^---
```

The `,` and `'` need to be swapped.

Comment: How could I miss that, lol

Comment: easy enough to miss that. Just be careful with this kind of thing. Unless you've taken precautions in code you didn't show, you're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables). You say you're just starting out, so start out properly: Switch to PDO or mysqli and use prepared statements. the mysql_*() function library is obsolete and deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

From the third line in your query

```
('$name','$area,''$esp',
```

There is a double `''` before $esp.